# Colocar conteúdo dentro do fopen PHP

Tags: php

Boa tarde, eu estou criando uma página nova a executar um comando pelo fopen, com o seguinte código:

```html
<?php
  $pagina  = 'pagina';
  $ext     = '.php';
  $arquivo = fopen ($pagina.$ext, 'w+');
  if ($arquivo == false) die('não foi possível criar o arquivo');
?>
```

a dúvida é, como faço para colocar um conteúdo pré determinado dentro do novo arquivo que foi criado, por exemplo um echo, ou seja assim que o novo arquivo for criado dentro dele já vim um echo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para isso, você deve usar a função [fwrite](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.fwrite.php).

```
<?php

  $pagina  = 'pagina';
  $ext     = '.php';
  $arquivo = fopen ($pagina.$ext, 'w+');
  fwrite($arquivo, '<?php echo "Qualquer texto inicial."; ?>');

  if ($arquivo == false) die('não foi possível criar o arquivo');

?>
```

Comment: Legal José! mais eu conseguiria colocar um código html? ou não?

Comment: Conseguiria sim, só trocar o conteúdo. Sem segredo! :)